# how can i see my ip:8080 externaly in apache server?

Tags: apache, laravel-5, vuejs2

i installed laravel and vue.js in an apache server. When i run vue from my terminal it works at http://localhost:8080. When i try to check it externally like http://138.68.xxx.xxx:8080/, i see only This site can’t be reached.

I visited http://portquiz.net:8080/ and the result is that:
You have reached this page on port 8080. Your network allows you to use this port.

I haven't done anything yet because i am not experienced with servers. I read about vhosts etc, but a guidance or help from someone more experienced would be more than welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Can you try to run app on `0.0.0.0:8080` instead of `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080`?

Comment: how do i do that?